# Is there a word for the state when something has "hit the mark"

Tags: single-word-requests

In Dutch one can say

> Schiet raak!

meaning

> Shoot in such a way that you hit what you intend to hit!

'Raak' is a word that is literally defined as "hitting it's goal" and it can for example also be used as a single word exclamation when something has hit it's intended goal ("Raak! Look, I hit triple 20 on the dart board!!!"). How would the same concept/sentiment be expressed in English? The closest I have come is "Don't miss!" and "Yeey, I didn't miss!", but that still feels quite a bit off.

Answer (score 5):

You say **"Bullseye!**"

> [bullseye](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullseye) *Interjection* A cry when someone hits the bullseye of a target.

But not used only when you hit the bullseye actually.

From [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bullseye):

> An expression used when an incredibly accurate shot has been made. Used commonly in fps games and in the military.
>
> *Guy 1: "Dude I did a headshot with this crappy handgun!"*
>
> *Guy 2: "Haha! Bullseye!"*

Comment: *But not used only when you hit the bullseye actually.* especially since we don't often hunt bulls!

Comment: Only 'problem' with this one is that for example with dart it's not about the intended target, but about the 'bullseye', so if you would want to throw a triple 3 or something and succeeded 'bullseye!' would seem quite the odd thing to shout :P

Answer (score 1):

Consider "Dead on (target)!"

Can also be used figuratively to mean that a statement is exactly correct or accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bullseye,

[**Bingo!**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bingo) it is the cry of successfully winning the game bingo.  And, it can also mean I've done it!

[**Eureka!**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eureka) for a discovery that hits the mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell someone to **shoot straight**, though you have to be carefully about the context since it's more associated with gunfire than arrows.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of sport terms:

- baseball: right down the middle and homerun
- football: split the uprights and touchdown
- golf: hole-in-one
- basketball: swish (nothing but net)

Answer (score 0):

You already have **bingo** and **bulls-eye** in previous answers. Can also use **right-on** to tell someone that they are correct.